# How to sync passwords between Windows Chrome and iCloud Keychain?

Tags: ios, safari, windows, google-chrome, keychain

How can I sync passwords between Chrome and iCloud Keychain, i.e. import passwords stored by Chrome on a Windows desktop computer to the iCloud keychain in order to be used on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can download [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283) and the [iCloud Passwords browser extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj).

Comment: Are you sure this will import chrome passwords into iCloud, or will this just allow iCloud passwords to be used in chrome on that specific machine?

Answer (score 0):

It's reported [here](https://www.hawkdive.com/how-to-use-icloud-passwords-in-chrome-for-windows/) that enabling the iCloud Password extension disables the native Chrome password manager.

I'm seeing ways to import Google passwords to Keychain on Mac, but not yet how to do it without a Mac.

> Note: Always remember that when you will enable the extension for iCloud Passwords, the native password manager for the Chrome browser will be turned off automatically.