How to choose a password storage strategy between windows spreadsheet and an iPhone?
Consider someone with an iPhone. Passwords are saved in a spreadsheet that is only on a Windows computer.
Chrome is installed on the iPhone but mainly Safari us used.
The solution mainly needs to be simple, but also secure.
Can the passwords sync with the Windows iCloud application, or with Chrome?

The way this question is worded it’s considered “off topic” as being opinion based.  However, if it were me, I would use an open source, cross platform (Windows, macOS, iOS, Android, Linux, etc) password manager like KeePassXC

Honestly I have seen this a lot in corporate offices. Honestly your best idea is to get (presumably) you and your girlfriend off of keeping passwords in a spreadsheet (search for Excel password crackers, they're everywhere). Get a password manager. I use 1Password but there are others. But this is a question that will attract only opinions and is likely to get closed.

@SteveChambers thanks for the comment. Those can and have been hacked via password resuse. I will have her use the icloud control panel on Windows.
Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438096/how-to-sync-passwords-between-windows-chrome-and-icloud-keychain?rq=1

@Allan
I am not looking for opinions or the best solution, just something that is workable. But I understand and respect the policies here.

@JustinGoldberg - with password managers you don't reuse passwords generate a different one for each site. Also the risk of the PM being broken that way is much less than an Excel spreadsheet

@mmmmm One obviously needs to choose a strong and memorable password for the password manager itself. Putting all password eggs into one basket and then protecting that basket with "Passw0rd" is not recommended :-)

Keeping passwords in a spreadsheet or text document is a bad idea for a lot of reasons. Using the password manager of a browser is at least better from a security and syncing point of view, but is bound to that browser (so if you need the same login/password in another browser or in an app, you are out of luck). The smart way to store and sync passwords across devices is to use a password manager. As a side effect, this will also allow you to automatically create passwords of reasonable length and complexity.

iCloud Keychain will work as long as you mainly use Apple devices and sometimes Windows, it is (AFAIK) not available on Linux.
1Password is a popular choice and available on all major platforms.
KeePassXC is the open source solution of choice, and also available on all major platforms.

PS: There are fan groups and people who don‘t like them for all these products, and various alternatives which offer similar functionality. Comparing these products to find the "best" is off-topic on AD, propose to do some research on your own if necessary.
